# Help on Apostol's explanation of Archimedes method?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading Apostol's *Calculus*, I don't understand what he's doing here (I've searched a bit, found explanations on [Square Pyramidal Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), Faulhaber's formula and Ehrhart polynomials) but none of them seem to be similar to the explanation Apostol gives here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I guess I just need a little bit more of context.

Comment: I'd also some like more context. What precisely is your question/confusion?

Comment: @neuguy For example, why start with $(k+1)^3$? I'm not really sure of what is happening in there, then I asked it vaguely: I was hoping that someone could rephrase it adding a little bit more detail perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(k+1)^3-k^3$ has no term with power $3$. Thus, he you can write the differences $(k+1)^3-k^3$ only on terms of $k^2, k$, which is precisely what you want; since the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)^3-k^3
$$
is telescopic, it equals $n^3-1$. On the other hand, you have
$$n^3-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)^3-k^3=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 3k^2+3k+1,$$
so you can now isolate $n^3$ to get your desired expression. Summarizing, the trick of considering $(k+1)^3-k^3=3k^2+3k+1$ is to get rid of the $k^3$ term and moreover to obtain a telescopic sum whenever you sum up those expressions. Eventually you could check if you got the trick by computing $\sum_{k=1}^n k^4$.